# Update Dynamics environment when migrating MS Flow

Tags: dynamics-crm, power-automate, common-data-service

I have got a Microsoft flow using a Dynamics (Common Data Service) connection. The Dynamics user I'm using can access several environments in the tenant.

If I export the flow and import it in a new environment I'm able to choose/create a new connection for the destination environment, so no problem there.

But I haven't found a way to change the "environment" variable so to the Dynamics connection is done to the destination "environment".

[image]

Is there any automated way to export+import  a flow and have this "environment" variable updated?

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to solve this using the "Current" option in the "Environment" dropdown list