# Trigger one flow from another flow

Tags: power-automate

I'm trying to call one flow from another flow so I have created the called one as "Request" triggered:

[image]

So this gives me an URL, Perfect! And I have included a HTTP call to that URL in the caller flow.

This works perfect. But if I export these flows from a source environment and import them into a destination environment the URL changes so this doesn't work.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Any follow up questions?

Answer (score 1):

Application lifecycle management (ALM) for Power Automate and Power Apps is still evolving. Deployment between the environments using Solution packaging, environmental variables are available but only for CDS enabled environments.

Still after shipping from lower region (Dev) to upper region (Prod) using Solutions, the connections has to be reestablished before activation of Flows.

> By default, when new flows are imported, they will be in a disabled state since connections still need to be established. Upon establishing connection(s) and saving the flow, the flow will become activated.

[Reference](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/solutions-in-microsoft-flow/)

That being said, you may need to manually change the HTTP url to map the new Flow url after import. This is the only way today.

Coming from the Dynamics CRM (CDS) background, I know how the earlier version of Workflow & child workflow deployment deploys seamlessly, I will expect that to happen in the future.

Comment: Great, I see you self-answered your other question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56176575/7920473